# Files are not playing locally after splitting in android

Tags: android, file, video

Hi i am splitting the **video** files  each one as **1MB** using below jave code  and they are splitting fine,But when i go to their physical local path and try to playing they are not playing and i am using FFMpeg also for this scenerio but that is also not working for me showing exception like **No such file or Dictionary**

please help me some one how can i resolve this problem

### code:

```
 public static List<File> splitFile(File f) {

    try {

        int partCounter = 1;
        List<File> result = new ArrayList<>();
        int sizeOfFiles = 1024 * 1024;// 1MB
        byte[] buffer = new byte[sizeOfFiles];
        // create a buffer of bytes sized as the one chunk size

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        String name = f.getName();

        int tmp = 0;
        while ((tmp = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            File newFile = new File(f.getParent(), name + "." + String.format("%03d", partCounter++));
            // naming files as <inputFileName>.001, <inputFileName>.002, ...
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            out.write(buffer, 0, tmp);//tmp is chunk size. Need it for the last chunk,
            // which could be less then 1 mb.
            result.add(newFile);
        }
        return result;
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

### FFMpegCode:-

```
     public void getSplitCommand(String inputFileUrl, String outputFileUrl) {

            inputFileUrl=  /storage/emulated/0/1492848702.mp4;
            outputFileUrl= /storage/emulated/0/1492848702.mp4;
      ;
 String cmd[] = new String[]{"-i ",inputFileUrl+" ","-c ","copy ","-map ","0 ",
                "-segment_time ","8 ","-f ","segment/sdcard/Download/output%03d.mp4"};
            executeBinaryCommand(fFmpeg, cmd);
        }


        /**
         * executeBinaryCommand
         *
         * @param ffmpeg
         * @param command
         */

        public void executeBinaryCommand(FFmpeg ffmpeg, String[] command) {

            try {

                if (ffmpeg != null) {

                    ffmpeg.execute(command,
                            new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(String response) {
                                    System.out.println("failure====>" + response.toString());
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(String response) {
                                    System.out.println("resposense====>" + response.toString());
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onProgress(String response) {
                                    System.out.println("on progress");
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onStart() {
                                    System.out.println("start");
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFinish() {
                                    System.out.println("Finish");
                                }
                            });
                }
            } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Use [FFMPEG][2] library to split video. your splitting method might be damage video. This will not happened with FFMPEG

ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -acodec copy -f segment -vcodec copy -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0 OUTPUT%d.mp4

[2]: https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/tree/master/FFmpegAndroid  i have split video into per 8 seconds. Dont split into size. Split always in duration

Comment: hi @Rajesh i already used FFMPEG for splitting files but showing error like No such file or Dictionary'

Comment: about FFMPEG i need your help if you dont mind ,Because i am facing this problem since 2 days

Comment: can i share my sample code to you if you dont mind?,just 10 lines code

Comment: hi your free now ?

Comment: Hi @rajesh i share my FFMpeg code please help me where i did mistack

Comment: this link is my sample project please ,I hope you can help me about FFMpeg

Comment: i will see it and reply you within 2 hour.Now plz don't more comment here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143369/discussion-between-rajesh-nasit-and-anil-kumar).

Comment: i am getting invalid aggument